# How to act against an auto boycott of the client?

Tags: management

I doubt I'll ever have to live something like that once again, but just in case I'd like to share my story.

I worked in a RPA software company which was hired to develop a certain project in which we were in contact with some employeers of the company that have hired us in charge of allowing us the needed things for the development of the application in computer terms (net, hard disk, IDEs...) and others of defining the needs of the application.

From the start things seemed fishy as they gave as some pretty strange excuses about compatibility and needing  to change there software installation needs according to what we developed, but my boss agreed... so we got a development enviroment... with no system control version, no IDE, just a text editor with syntaxis enhacement and for the development language... VBSCRIPT!!!

But that was only the beginning, things went even worse when people of defining the needs of the application, as in three months from the beginning of developing the application there was already a version 5 of the initial functional, that without considering some other changes that were done that weren't explicitly asked on the functional. At this point it was pretty clear for me that application would never be developed because of that people, as they were afraid of getting fired as their job would get reduced (people in charge of computing and development wouldn't be able to change much web pages because of the software and people that were in charge and people in charge of giving us the instructions might lose their job if the software already did their job). At this point I saw almost no point in continuing there, I was wondering things like this is pretty pointless whatever I do isn't going to be valid, making effort in this is stupid I'm just delaying the inevitable, so whether I work hard or not is just going to maybe delay my firing on a month, they are laughing directly at me and despite that I've to put a good face, I was also already sort of tired of having to work hard to adapt the application to their always changing requests.

From that point with that thoughs my performance went down by a lot pretty slowing the project, so 1 month and 15 days (with a version 9 of the functional document along with soome other changes) after I finally got fired for low performance having to endure some arguments to my boss meanwhile. Funniest thing is that he was saying the people we had to work with was the most useless he had ever worked with, meanwhile I was thinking... well in reality they are being smart... for their own purposes.

Ironically enough 9 days latter he sent me a whatsapp message by error telling that the client had decided to cancel the project, I almost felt like saying him... I knew it...

What do you think it would me good to do if a situation like this happens ever again?

Than you.

Comment: I don't see how the term "boycott" is at all applicable here.

Comment: Well certainly don't post about it here.

Comment: "What do you think it would me good to do if a situation like this happens ever again?" Avoid it! Don't ever work for a spineless boss ever again. Ask tough questions during your interview. Ask your future employers point-blank questions like: "If a client refused to allow your team to use such and such a tool. Would you be ok with that?" "Describe your current development environment." "How do you fare on Joel's ten questions?" and ask those questions again and again with the other employees that you'll meet. "How would your manager react if a client... blah blah" etc.

Answer (score 7):

> What do you think it would me good to do if a situation like this happens ever again?

Collect your pay and spend it.

Many jobs I have done, particularly govt but some bigger businesses have been a total waste of time for the client. No real attempt was made to bring the projects to successful fruition. Too many people were involved and no one really knew what they wanted. They had a budget they had to spend, and they spent it. Budget ran out, project dried up. Next year they'll ask for a bigger budget.

I just did what I was paid to do, they could change the requirements all they wanted, start over from scratch if they want, so long as I was getting paid.

Answer (score 2):

The next time that you have, such a serious issue like "I saw almost no point in continuing there", go to your boss, explain that you see a big financial risk (project cancellation) in professional language, and state that you think it would make more sense to work on another project.

Not sure about his reaction, but when the project is cancelled, he may thank you for letting him know beforehand.